# pass scroll event from uibutton to uiscrollview

Tags: iphone, scroll, uiscrollview, uibutton

i have horizontal `UIScrollView` which is extended from `UIScrollView` and i added `UIButtons` horizontally. i can only scroll out of the buttons area, but if i want to scroll over any buttons is fires `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` event. I don't want this. i want to fire `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` action if i click and i want to scroll if i scroll.

so how can i pass scroll event from `UIButton` to `UIScrollView`?

Comment: It would help if you created a simple code example to illustrate what you are doing, because in the simple case of adding a UIButton to a UIScrollView, you can drag the scroll view postion around even if you started the touch event on a button.

Answer (score 4):

Subclass UIScrollView, return YES in the `- touchesShouldCancelInContentView:` method.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :]

Answer (score 3):

that functionality is already built in. When you have a UIControl element as a subview of a scroll view and a touch event is detected, it is initially passed to the UIScrollView. IF, after a moment or two there hasn't been sufficient movement in the touch event, it gets passed on to the button.

Comment: I wanted my buttons to float above the scrolling content in a fixed position, rather than move with the content as they would do if they were subviews of the scroll view. But I couldn't get the touch events flowing properly with any other approach, so I tried this approach and grouped all my buttons into a view that is a subview of the scroll view. I'm keeping that view above the visible content by setting its frame.origin.x to match the scroll view's contentOffset.x whenever the content is scrolled, as detected by the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method. That works!

Answer (score 0):

If you subclass NSButton and make your button of that type and override the following in your subclass you can pass the events back to the parent view, in your case the scroll view

The following would make the button never trigger an event and instead all would be dealt with by the parent view:

```
- (void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];      
}

- (void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];  
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{
    [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];  
}
```

If you want to have the button deal with one of those events instead use

```
[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. The reason is that UIScrollView doesn't respond to touchesBegan, touchesMoved and touchesEnded events. I subclassed UIScrollView to confirm that it was receiving these events, but not doing anything with them. As an alternative to passing the touch events, you can calculate the change in position in touchesMoved and alter the scroll view's contentOffset property, but that doesn't give you any of the smooth movement or inertia of the normal scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
self.button.exclusiveTouch = YES
```

Worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your scrollview has:
.delaysContentTouches = true