# UIButton that will ignore a 'drag' and pass it to UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uiscrollview, uibutton

I know there are similar posts on Stack but nothing that I've found has helped me find a solution.

- I have a **scrollview** added to a **UIView**.
- I have added a **UIButton** to the **same UIView above the scrollview**.

  1. I want the UIButton to respond to a touchUp and fire an event.
  2. If someone **DRAGS** on the UIButton I want it to *pass the event to the scrollView and drag the UIScrollView without firing the button event.*

I know how to pass on a touch with hitTest returning the scrollview but this stops anything getting to the UIButton.

I **don't** want to add the UIButton to the UIScrollView.

Does anyone have a proposed solution?

Comment: regarding this old question.  If you have a subview, X, of a scroll view ***it's totally OK to make X have constraints that attached to the overall view and NOT to the scroll view!***  Very simply, X then will not scroll. It just sits on top.  It's that easy!

Comment: Just to repeat that explanation:  Say the button B is a subview of a scroll view S and the scroll view is sitting in an overall view, say V.  Surprisingly, B ***does have to scroll***.  Again B does NOT have to scroll. Simply attach B to V (not to S) and you're done.  It's actually that simple.

Comment: Thus looking at the question exactly as stated by Morgz, simply in point 2 YES make the button a subview of the scroll view, but surprisingly simply constraint the button to the overall UIView!  It's that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733829/pass-scroll-event-from-uibutton-to-uiscrollview#answer-4839433), a UIButton or other UIControl that is a subview of a scroll view will automatically respond to taps while letting the scroll view handle drags. However, buttons that are subviews of the scroll view will also move with the scrolled content, rather than remaining in the same position on the screen as the content scrolls beneath them. I assume this is why you don't want to put the buttons into the scroll view.

If that's the case, you can get the desired behavior with one more step. Put all your buttons into a UIView that is a subview of the scroll view, then in the scrollViewDidScroll method of the scroll view's delegate, set that view's frame.origin to the scroll view's contentOffset. I just implemented this in my app and it's working great, without having to do any subclassing or get involved with the responder chain or touch events.

Comment: The first para here is totally correct.  ***But the second paragraph is not necessary! it's totally OK to have the subview constrained to the SUPERVIEW of the scrollview!!***  Very simply, the subview will then not scroll. It just sits on top.  It's that easy!

Comment: @Fattie Keep in mind that auto-layout didn't exist when this question and its answers were written. But posting a new answer using current coding tools would be nice.

Comment: lol, fantastic point @arlomedia !!  yeah, truly old QA on SO is becoming a problem.  many of my earliest answers are completely legacy now and refer to non-existent technologies

Comment: @Fattie Fortunately everything is clearly dated, so I always keep the age in mind when browsing posts.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: Subclassing UIScrollView, return YES in the touchesShouldCancelInContentView: method.

Comment: Work for me! Thank you very much ! :]

Comment: I don't think this is correct?  Note that in the question the buttons are on **top** of the scroll, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Add a transparent, custom UIView as big as the entire scroll view contentSize to the scroll view, over all the other views. (Or alternatively, make it as big as the scroll view width/height and simply move it every time the scroll view moves.) When the scroll view decides to pass on its touches to its subviews instead of dragging, this will be the first thing hitTested.
2. Override the hitTest method for the UIView. Check if the touch is within your button frame. If it is, return the button; if not, return nil.

In effect, you'd be tricking the scroll view into thinking that the button is one of its subviews. I'm not certain this will work as I haven't actually tried it, but it seems entirely sensible.

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't make it work. The problem is that hitTest is called on the view whether you swipe the scroll view or just tap it, so the custom hitTest method doesn't know whether to pass the event through to the scroll view, or redirect it to the button. I also tried using touchesMoved in the custom view to calculate whether it's receiving a touch or a tap, but by the time touchesMove is called, the hitTest method is finished, so there's no way to respond conditionally there.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the `UIBUtton`. In the callback you specify to handle the pan (drag), you need not implement anything. Then, set `cancelsTouchesInView` to YES. This will cause your button to passed drag gestures to the other views.

```
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan)];
        [gr setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
        [myButton addGestureRecognizer:gr];
        [gr release];
```

And here's `handlePan`:

```
-(void)handlePan
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

I ran into a similar situation where I had a `UIScrollView` with two `UIView` subviews. Each `UIView` contained a `UISlider`. I wanted to catch (and drop) vertical drags (which is where the gesture recognizer came in), but I also needed horizontal scrolls to work in the slider as you'd expect AND to pan the scroll view left and right. This was the solution. (The gesture recognizer was attached to each `UIView`.)

Comment: Didn't work for me, though my setup is slightly different.  Rather than a scrollView, I just have a viewController with several views on it that can be dragged around.  My problem is that some of those subviews have buttons (because they react to tap), and the buttons block the dragging behaviour.  I'd-a thought that this answer would solve it but, alas, no.  :\   Any additional hints would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: For clarification, I also tried duplicating the `gr` onto the littler subview that contains the button, hoping to pass the pan all the way through to its superview.  No joy.